# Killing a node.js server (launched in jest's setup hook) in jest teardown

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) as a testing library and inside its [setup hook](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown) (which is executed before all my tests), I [spawn](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) a child process which launches a testing server on a certain port.
The setup code basically executes an NPM command:

```js
"run-server-test": "NODE_ENV=test SERVER_PORT=3001 node src/index.js &",
"test": "NODE_ENV=test SERVER_PORT=3001 jest --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
```

And this is the setup function:

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process")

module.exports = async function setup() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const testServerProcess = spawn("npm", ["run", "run-server-test"])

    testServerProcess.on("error", err => {
      console.log("Failed to start subprocess.", err)
      reject(err)
    })

    testServerProcess.stdout.on("data", data => {
      if (data.toString().startsWith("Apollo Server")) {
        console.log(`\nTest server running with PID ${testServerProcess.pid}`)
        resolve(true)
      }
    })

    testServerProcess.stderr.on("data", data => {
      console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
      reject(new Error(data.toString()))
    })
  })
}
```

Notice that I execute the command in background with `&`. When Jest finishes its job, I notice with `ps` that its PID it's different from the one shown in the shell. Without executing it in the background, I get an extra process, the shell's one (`/bin/sh`).
How could I get the real PID of that process?
Is there a best way to kill the process launched inside that function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My current approach is the following:

- wrap the Express bootstrap process inside a function which returns the `httpServer` instance used to make the server listen to requests. This is a good case for `beforeAll` hook.
- use the previous reference to close the server in the `afterAll`.

Another alternative (a bit tricky), could be to launch the server once at the beginning of all your tests and close it at the end:

- directly spawn the node process instead of passing through `npm`
- store the process ID in a temporary mongo's collection (but could be anything)
- in the teardown, I retrieve the PID and then I just do `process.kill(PID, "SIGTERM")`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a start and stop method on your sever.  Then you don't need to worry about forking your processes.

I'm using express as an example.

app.js

```
const start = async (callback => { 
  await database.connect();
  server.listen(config.port, config.ip, () => {
    callback();
  });
};

const stop = (callback => {
  server.close(async () => {
    await database.disconnect();
    callback();
  });
};
```

app.test.js

```
const server = require('./path/to/server');

beforeAll(async () => {
  try {
    await server.start();
  } catch (error) {
    // if the server doesn't start up or the seeding fails, just
    // exit the process ASAP
    process.exit(1);  
  }
});

afterAll(done => {
  server.stop(done);
});
```